# SQL View merge with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have multiple tables of roles (e.g. student, guest, teacher) and a table of users with their id's.

I want to make a SQL view which has the userId and Role ("student", "teacher" ...) as a string.

The roles tables each have a foreign userId but don't have the role as text string. So there should be some kind of comparator, if the user has an id in student then its role is "student".

How would you start writing this ?

Comment: A very odd database design if you dont mind me saying so

Comment: I don't mind. Its for learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each of the role tables has 0 or 1 records per user, you could use a series of `left join`s:

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    CASE 
        WHEN s.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'student'
        WHEN g.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'guest'
        WHEN t.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'teacher'
        ELSE 'unknown'
    END role
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN students s ON s.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN guests g ON g.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN teacher t ON t.id = u.id
```

If a user may have more than one role, you could split the information over several boolean columns:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    CASE
    s.id IS NOT NULL is_teacher,
    g.id IS NOT NULL is_guest,
    t.id IS NOT NULL then is_teaacher
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN students s ON s.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN guests g ON g.id = s.id
LEFT JOIN teacher t ON t.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT u.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM students s WHERE s.user_id = u.user_id)
             THEN 'student'
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM guests g WHERE g.user_id = u.user_id)
             THEN 'guest'
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM teachers t WHERE t.user_id = u.user_id)
             THEN 'teacher'
             ELSE '???'
        END) AS role
FROM users u;
```

This assumes that each user has only one role.  This can be modified (using `concat()`) to handle multiple roles.